# sed: remove spaces from the log using regular expression

Tags: sed

i am dealing with the log consisted of many lines in the following format:

```
06I: 31 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.1/? THR 26 N       #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? THR 26 H       3.515  2.716
 #1.1/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.227  2.305
 #1.1/A UNL 1 N        #1.1/? THR 26 O     #1.1/A UNL 1 H        3.463  2.652
 #1.2/A UNL 1 N        #1.2/? PHE 140 O    #1.2/A UNL 1 H        2.987  2.200
 #1.4/? THR 26 N       #1.4/A UNL 1 S      #1.4/? THR 26 H       4.354  3.371
 #1.4/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen                                          3.137  N/A
 #1.4/A UNL 1 N        #1.4/? ARG 188 O    #1.4/A UNL 1 H        3.000  2.081
 #1.5/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen                                          3.330  N/A
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 O      #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.029  2.132
 #1.6/A UNL 1 N        #1.6/? ARG 188 O    #1.6/A UNL 1 H        2.984  2.064
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 N      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.164  2.395
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.031  2.180
 #1.8/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.276  2.553
 #1.8/A UNL 1 N        #1.8/? THR 190 O    #1.8/A UNL 1 H        3.257  2.407
 #1.9/A UNL 1 N        #1.9/? THR 190 O    #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.913  2.037
 #1.10/? SER 144 OG    #1.10/A UNL 1 S     #1.10/? SER 144 HG    4.246  3.845
 #1.10/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen                                          3.700  N/A
 #1.10/A UNL 1 N       #1.10/? THR 190 O   #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.008  2.091
 #1.12/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.12/A UNL 1 O     #1.12/? GLN 189 1HE2  2.929  2.152
 #1.12/A UNL 1 N       #1.12/? PHE 140 O   #1.12/A UNL 1 H       2.912  2.012
 #1.13/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.13/A UNL 1 O     #1.13/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.063  2.291
 #1.14/? HIS 41 NE2    #1.14/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen                                          3.919  N/A
 #1.14/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.14/A UNL 1 O     #1.14/? ASN 142 2HD2  2.802  1.872
 #1.14/A UNL 1 N       #1.14/? THR 190 O   #1.14/A UNL 1 H       2.927  1.987
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 N     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.456  2.669
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 O     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.079  2.177
 #1.16/A UNL 1 N       #1.16/? THR 190 O   #1.16/A UNL 1 H       2.967  1.987
 #1.17/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.17/A UNL 1 N     #1.17/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.218  2.294
 #1.17/A UNL 1 N       #1.17/? THR 190 O   #1.17/A UNL 1 H       3.364  2.469
 #1.18/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.18/A UNL 1 O     #1.18/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.117  2.142
 #1.20/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.20/A UNL 1 N     #1.20/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.245  2.560
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
structure30R: 21 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.4/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 O       #1.4/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.139  2.374
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N       #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.296  2.365
 #1.7/? CYS 145 SG     #1.7/A UNL 1 O       #1.7/? CYS 145 HG     3.466  2.762
 #1.7/A UNL 1 O        #1.7/? LEU 141 O     #1.7/A UNL 1 H        2.951  2.048
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.660  3.073
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 1HD2   2.965  2.162
 #1.8/? CYS 145 SG     #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? CYS 145 HG     3.480  2.556
 #1.9/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.9/A UNL 1 O      no hydrogen                                                   3.272  N/A
 #1.9/A UNL 1 O        #1.9/? GLN 189 OE1   #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.915  2.341
 #1.10/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.100  2.185
 #1.10/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.180  2.408
 #1.10/A UNL 1 O       #1.10/? GLU 166 O    #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.246  2.639
 #1.11/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O      #1.11/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.122  2.204
 #1.11/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O     no hydrogen                                                   3.313  N/A
```

as you may see some lines (which consist of the pattern "no hydrogen" + some number os spaces) are out of the format where the last two numbers are significantly shifted e.g. `no hydrogen                                          3.137  N/A`

Since the number of the spaces between these elements may be different I could not find a simple expression using sed to remove all of those useless spaces e.g.

```
sed -e "s/no hydrogen                     //g"
```

will match only for a partcilar line.
may you suggest me some regular expressiion which can be used with sed to match all the lines consisted of "no hydrogen" and remove the unused spaces?

Here is the expected output:

```
06I: 31 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.1/? THR 26 N       #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? THR 26 H       3.515  2.716
 #1.1/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.227  2.305
 #1.1/A UNL 1 N        #1.1/? THR 26 O     #1.1/A UNL 1 H        3.463  2.652
 #1.2/A UNL 1 N        #1.2/? PHE 140 O    #1.2/A UNL 1 H        2.987  2.200
 #1.4/? THR 26 N       #1.4/A UNL 1 S      #1.4/? THR 26 H       4.354  3.371
 #1.4/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen            3.137  N/A
 #1.4/A UNL 1 N        #1.4/? ARG 188 O    #1.4/A UNL 1 H        3.000  2.081
 #1.5/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen            3.330  N/A
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 O      #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.029  2.132
 #1.6/A UNL 1 N        #1.6/? ARG 188 O    #1.6/A UNL 1 H        2.984  2.064
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 N      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.164  2.395
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.031  2.180
 #1.8/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.276  2.553
 #1.8/A UNL 1 N        #1.8/? THR 190 O    #1.8/A UNL 1 H        3.257  2.407
 #1.9/A UNL 1 N        #1.9/? THR 190 O    #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.913  2.037
 #1.10/? SER 144 OG    #1.10/A UNL 1 S     #1.10/? SER 144 HG    4.246  3.845
 #1.10/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen            3.700  N/A
 #1.10/A UNL 1 N       #1.10/? THR 190 O   #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.008  2.091
 #1.12/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.12/A UNL 1 O     #1.12/? GLN 189 1HE2  2.929  2.152
 #1.12/A UNL 1 N       #1.12/? PHE 140 O   #1.12/A UNL 1 H       2.912  2.012
 #1.13/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.13/A UNL 1 O     #1.13/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.063  2.291
 #1.14/? HIS 41 NE2    #1.14/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen            3.919  N/A
 #1.14/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.14/A UNL 1 O     #1.14/? ASN 142 2HD2  2.802  1.872
 #1.14/A UNL 1 N       #1.14/? THR 190 O   #1.14/A UNL 1 H       2.927  1.987
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 N     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.456  2.669
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 O     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.079  2.177
 #1.16/A UNL 1 N       #1.16/? THR 190 O   #1.16/A UNL 1 H       2.967  1.987
 #1.17/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.17/A UNL 1 N     #1.17/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.218  2.294
 #1.17/A UNL 1 N       #1.17/? THR 190 O   #1.17/A UNL 1 H       3.364  2.469
 #1.18/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.18/A UNL 1 O     #1.18/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.117  2.142
 #1.20/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.20/A UNL 1 N     #1.20/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.245  2.560
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
structure30R: 21 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.4/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 O       #1.4/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.139  2.374
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N       #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.296  2.365
 #1.7/? CYS 145 SG     #1.7/A UNL 1 O       #1.7/? CYS 145 HG     3.466  2.762
 #1.7/A UNL 1 O        #1.7/? LEU 141 O     #1.7/A UNL 1 H        2.951  2.048
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.660  3.073
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 1HD2   2.965  2.162
 #1.8/? CYS 145 SG     #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? CYS 145 HG     3.480  2.556
 #1.9/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.9/A UNL 1 O      no hydrogen            3.272  N/A
 #1.9/A UNL 1 O        #1.9/? GLN 189 OE1   #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.915  2.341
 #1.10/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.100  2.185
 #1.10/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.180  2.408
 #1.10/A UNL 1 O       #1.10/? GLU 166 O    #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.246  2.639
 #1.11/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O      #1.11/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.122  2.204
 #1.11/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O     no hydrogen
```

Comment: thanks! I've just added it to the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(no hydrogen \{12\}\)[[:space:]]\+/\1/' input_fie
06I: 31 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.1/? THR 26 N       #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? THR 26 H       3.515  2.716
 #1.1/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.1/A UNL 1 O      #1.1/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.227  2.305
 #1.1/A UNL 1 N        #1.1/? THR 26 O     #1.1/A UNL 1 H        3.463  2.652
 #1.2/A UNL 1 N        #1.2/? PHE 140 O    #1.2/A UNL 1 H        2.987  2.200
 #1.4/? THR 26 N       #1.4/A UNL 1 S      #1.4/? THR 26 H       4.354  3.371
 #1.4/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen            3.137  N/A
 #1.4/A UNL 1 N        #1.4/? ARG 188 O    #1.4/A UNL 1 H        3.000  2.081
 #1.5/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N     no hydrogen            3.330  N/A
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 O      #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.029  2.132
 #1.6/A UNL 1 N        #1.6/? ARG 188 O    #1.6/A UNL 1 H        2.984  2.064
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 N      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.164  2.395
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.031  2.180
 #1.8/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O      #1.8/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.276  2.553
 #1.8/A UNL 1 N        #1.8/? THR 190 O    #1.8/A UNL 1 H        3.257  2.407
 #1.9/A UNL 1 N        #1.9/? THR 190 O    #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.913  2.037
 #1.10/? SER 144 OG    #1.10/A UNL 1 S     #1.10/? SER 144 HG    4.246  3.845
 #1.10/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen            3.700  N/A
 #1.10/A UNL 1 N       #1.10/? THR 190 O   #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.008  2.091
 #1.12/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.12/A UNL 1 O     #1.12/? GLN 189 1HE2  2.929  2.152
 #1.12/A UNL 1 N       #1.12/? PHE 140 O   #1.12/A UNL 1 H       2.912  2.012
 #1.13/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.13/A UNL 1 O     #1.13/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.063  2.291
 #1.14/? HIS 41 NE2    #1.14/A UNL 1 S    no hydrogen            3.919  N/A
 #1.14/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.14/A UNL 1 O     #1.14/? ASN 142 2HD2  2.802  1.872
 #1.14/A UNL 1 N       #1.14/? THR 190 O   #1.14/A UNL 1 H       2.927  1.987
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 N     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.456  2.669
 #1.16/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.16/A UNL 1 O     #1.16/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.079  2.177
 #1.16/A UNL 1 N       #1.16/? THR 190 O   #1.16/A UNL 1 H       2.967  1.987
 #1.17/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.17/A UNL 1 N     #1.17/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.218  2.294
 #1.17/A UNL 1 N       #1.17/? THR 190 O   #1.17/A UNL 1 H       3.364  2.469
 #1.18/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.18/A UNL 1 O     #1.18/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.117  2.142
 #1.20/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.20/A UNL 1 N     #1.20/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.245  2.560
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
structure30R: 21 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.4/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.4/A UNL 1 O       #1.4/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.139  2.374
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 N       #1.5/? GLN 189 2HE2   3.296  2.365
 #1.7/? CYS 145 SG     #1.7/A UNL 1 O       #1.7/? CYS 145 HG     3.466  2.762
 #1.7/A UNL 1 O        #1.7/? LEU 141 O     #1.7/A UNL 1 H        2.951  2.048
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.660  3.073
 #1.8/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? ASN 142 1HD2   2.965  2.162
 #1.8/? CYS 145 SG     #1.8/A UNL 1 O       #1.8/? CYS 145 HG     3.480  2.556
 #1.9/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.9/A UNL 1 O      no hydrogen            3.272  N/A
 #1.9/A UNL 1 O        #1.9/? GLN 189 OE1   #1.9/A UNL 1 H        2.915  2.341
 #1.10/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.100  2.185
 #1.10/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O      #1.10/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.180  2.408
 #1.10/A UNL 1 O       #1.10/? GLU 166 O    #1.10/A UNL 1 H       3.246  2.639
 #1.11/? ASN 142 ND2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O      #1.11/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.122  2.204
 #1.11/? HIS 163 NE2   #1.11/A UNL 1 O     no hydrogen
```

`\(no hydrogen \{12\}\)` - Create a group match within parenthesis `(..)` with `sed`s back referencing functionality which can later be returned with `\1`. The command could also have been written `\(no hydrogen[[:space:]]\{12\}\)` to emphasize the presence of a space. This will include 12 spaces after the word `no hydrogen` to be returned as a back reference.

`[[:space:]]\+` - As this is not part of the group match, it will be excluded. This will match all the remaining spaces after the matched word and 12 spaces we want retained within the group match.

Comment: In fact, I've just tried your sollution but I don't see any difference between input/output...

Comment: @MaîtreRenard Did you copy the entire code correctly?

Comment: yep, actually I tried to integrate it into my script as cat $log | sed -e "s/\(no hydrogen \{12\}\)[[:space:]]\+/\1/" >> output and it did not work. but I also made a quick test: sed 's/\(no hydrogen \{12\}\)[[:space:]]\+/\1/' input.log >> test.log and I could not see any difference between input and output.

Comment: @MaîtreRenard The code you have provided is not the same as mine. You have literal `()` instead of grouping. As my code does not use `-E` for extended regex, you need to escape it as it is in my code. As your code is, you will need `-E` for it to work `sed -Ee 's/(no hydrogen {12})[[:space:]]+/\1/' input.log >> test.log`

Comment: @MaîtreRenard It should actually have thrown a RHS error.

Comment: Many thanks! the version with sed -Ee works correctly. May you please explain (briefly) what is the difference between -e and -Ee and how the regular expression actually works (how many spaces it detects after the pattern "no hydrogen" ) ?

Comment: @MaîtreRenard I will add an explanation of the code shortly. Regarding `-E`, it is for extended regex. `-Ee` is the same as `-E -e`, `-e` on its own is simply an expression with no extended regex features so you will still need to escape. You can run multiple `sed` commands in one pass with `-e` before each command.

Comment: Right, thank you! Actually I've merged two sed expressions together for log post-processing like sed -e "s/[[:alnum:]_]*\.pdb//g;1,${remove_lines}d" -Ee "s/(no hydrogen {12})[[:space:]]+/\1/" input.log >> output.log           so the first part works well with sed -e, while the second one is required for -Ee